# How to create some sort of word mapping?

Tags: localization

I would like to know how I could create a file in which I could associate a word in multiple languages. Let's make an example in XML:

```
<item key="goodMorning>
    <copy lang="en">Good morning<copy>
    <copy lang="fr">Bon matin<copy>
    <copy lang="nl">Goedemorgen<copy>
</item>
```

Is there such a file, or many files, that would be available for me to output a certain string to the front end according to the language? (It doesn't have to be XML at all, as long as it works in Wordpress).

This info (http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/custom-language-switcher/) allows me to get what is the current language, but I'd like to act accordingly.

I already use the WPML (paid) plugin, I asked the question over there as well, to no avail so far. If anyone could help, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your words in a WordPress translation tag in your theme:

```
<?php _e('Goedemorgen','yourthemename');?>
```

And with the WPML string translation tool you can scan for these strings and give the appropriate translation. That's how I do it with the paying WPML plugin. Works like a breeze.

No need to make your own pot translation files (that's maybe the answer you were initially looking for, but the WPML plugin makes things easier)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, with that I managed to translate a lot. However, my child theme requires additional strings, how do I add those strings? I'd rather avoid touching the parent theme.

Comment: You can add that code too to your child theme instead of only the main theme. The 'yourthemename' can be anything. You can also name it 'yourchildthemename'.